# Next js serve static js files not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

**I have this folder structure for my next.js project**

```
/public
    |static
        -hello.png
    |sample
        -test.js
    |charting_libray
        |bundle
            -dist.js
    |hello.png
```

In my local environment

```
http://localhost:3000/static/hello.webp

http://localhost:3000/hello.webp

http://localhost:3000/static/sample/test.js
```

All of these works. This means JS, Image anything can be served from nested folders or directly from the public folder.

But when I build the project using `next build` command and deployed it to the production.

```
mydomain.com/static/hello.webp
    
mydomain.com/hello.webp
    
mydomain.com/static/sample/test.js
```

I have noticed only the images files can be accessed and the JS file returns 404.

My real-world use case is, inside a component I pass the path to a library like this

```
libraryPath: "/static/charting_library/"
```

I can see a **net::ERR_ABORTED 404** error in the prod env browser console. Somehow the library works even with this 404 error.

But I need to know the reason for this 404 error and need to fix in the code.
Any help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be any number of issues, but most likely the files aren't there in production or a proxy in front of Next is causing issues. Have you verified that the files are present in production?

Comment: Can you replicate the issue when running the production build locally (`next build && next start`)?